# When a query includes a relationship, how can I use pattern matching on the included table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord, arel

Orders have many LineItems. LineItems have names, like "car". I want to find all the orders that have line items with names matching some pattern.

I know I can do `LineItem.where('name ~* :pat', pat: 'car')`, for example.

I also know I can do

```
Order.where.not(state: "cancelled")
     .includes(:line_items)
     .where(line_items: { name: "car" })
```

I'm not sure on the syntax for combining the two queries. I imagine it is something like,

```
Orders.where.not(state: 'cancelled')
      .includes(:line_items)
      .where(line_items: ['name ~* :pat', pat: 'car'])
```

This is tricky to google, so I thought I'd put it to you.

NOTE: last time I had a question about Rails activerecord, part of the solution was to inspect the SQL. In this case, though, use of the includes method results in some crazy scary SQL. Try something like this,

```
Order.includes(:line_items).where(line_item: { name: "car"}).to_sql
```

in your rails console for a good time!

NOTES: I need help with the title of this question, clearly.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-eager-loaded-associations),

> Using where like this will only work when you pass it a Hash. 
>   For SQL-fragments you need use references to force joined tables:

```
Post.includes(:comments).where("comments.visible = true").references(:comments)
```

So in my case, the query would be:

```
Orders.where.not(state: 'cancelled')
      .includes(:line_items)
      .where('line_items.name ~* ?', 'car').references(:line_items)
```

This returns all the orders with line items having names matching the given regex, with those line items pre-loaded. If you would rather not preload the line items, use `joins` instead of `includes`.

I'm not sure what you would do if you wanted to pre-load all the line items for each order, regardless of the condition (but hopefully I won't need to ^o^//).

EDIT: [this article](http://blog.arkency.com/2013/12/rails4-preloading/) shed a lot of light on what exactly is going on, and answered my second question. To pre-load all the line items you have to use... `preload` ha!

```
Orders.where.not(state: 'cancelled')
      .joins(:line_items) # note the joins
      .where('line_items.name ~* ?', 'car').references(:line_items)
      .preload(:line_items)
```

If you use `.includes` again here, you will be dissapointed. It has to be `preload`. This query gets me the orders I want, and preloads all the line items regardless of whether they matched the regex used to filter the orders.